# how do I set the charset when using clickhouse-client import CSV

Tags: csv, clickhouse

how do I set the charset when using clickhouse-client import CSV

clickhouse-client --query="INSERT INTO test FORMAT CSV" < test.csv

I want to set charset="UTF-8" but not find A option

Answer (score 0):

No such feature.

CH does not have charsets. CH stores Strings as is.

CH understands BOM automatically.

Just execute `clickhouse-client --query="INSERT INTO test FORMAT CSV" < test.csv`
It should work.